# What determines the cost of each index in the same table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL server 12 and psql 12.
I have a really huge table(about 6 million tuples) which has several columns. Say it's like

```
People(
   bigint id,
   varchar company_type,
   bigint complany_id,
   varchar department_type,
   bigint department_id,
   ......
)
```

And I have several indexes:

```
"people_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id),
"unique_person" UNIQUE, btree (company_type, company_id, department_type, department_id),
"company" btree (company_type, company_id),
"department" btree (department_type, department_id)
```

Now I have this simple query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT array(
    SELECT DISTINCT my_people.company_id
    FROM people AS my_people
    WHERE
    "my_people"."company_type" = 'Some_company' AND
    "my_people"."department_type" = 'Some_department' AND
    "my_people"."department_id" = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
) a

                                                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=8.60..8.61 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=2.377..2.378 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Unique  (cost=0.56..8.60 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.373..2.374 rows=0 loops=1)
           ->  Index Scan using company on people my_people  (cost=0.56..8.60 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.373..2.373 rows=0 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: ((company_type)::text = 'Some_company'::text)
                 Filter: ((department_type)::text = 'Some_department'::text) AND (department_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}'::integer[])))
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1189
 Planning Time: 0.873 ms
 Execution Time: 2.405 ms
```

The query time would be optimized if it uses the "department" index but instead doing so, it uses "company".

I've tried using pg_hint_plan to force it to use indexes I desire and it would be much faster than "company".

```
/*+ IndexScan(my_people department) */ EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT array(
    SELECT DISTINCT my_people.company_id
    FROM people AS my_people
    WHERE
    "my_people"."company_type" = 'Some_company' AND
    "my_people"."department_type" = 'Some_department' AND
    "my_people"."department_id" = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
) a

                                                                                                                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=503435.96..503435.97 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.073..0.074 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Unique  (cost=503435.95..503435.96 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.070..0.071 rows=0 loops=1)
           ->  Sort  (cost=503435.95..503435.96 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.070..0.071 rows=0 loops=1)
                 Sort Key: my_people.id
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                 ->  Index Scan using department on people my_people  (cost=0.56..503435.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.066..0.067 rows=0 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (((department_type)::text = 'Some_department'::text) AND (department_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}'::integer[])))
                       Filter: ((Company_type)::text = 'Some_company'::text)
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 0.252 ms
 Execution Time: 0.096 ms
(12 rows)


/*+ IndexScan(my_people unique_person) */ EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT array(
    SELECT DISTINCT my_people.company_id
    FROM people AS my_people
    WHERE
    "my_people"."company_type" = 'Some_company' AND
    "my_people"."department_type" = 'Some_department' AND
    "my_people"."department_id" = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
) a
                                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=8.60..8.61 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1.821..1.822 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Unique  (cost=0.56..8.60 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.818..1.818 rows=0 loops=1)
           ->  Index Scan using unique_person on people my_people  (cost=0.56..8.60 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.817..1.817 rows=0 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (((company_type)::text = 'Some_company'::text) AND ((department_type)::text = 'Some_department'::text))
                 Filter: (department_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}'::integer[]))
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 994
 Planning Time: 0.258 ms
 Execution Time: 1.842 ms
(9 rows)
```

Then I thought maybe it's the `ScalarArrayOpExpr` that makes it inefficient. So I changed the query to this. This is significantly faster but I still have to hint postgres to use "department" index.

```
/*+ IndexScan(my_people department) */ EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT array(
                SELECT a.*
                FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) as t(fid)
                    , LATERAL (
                SELECT DISTINCT my_people.id
                FROM people AS my_people
                WHERE
                  "my_people"."company_type" = 'Some_company' AND
                  "my_people"."department_type" = 'Some_department' AND
                  "my_people"."target_id" = t.fid
                ) a
              ) b
;
                                                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=3658.94..3658.95 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.092..0.094 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=522.67..3658.94 rows=7 width=8) (actual time=0.090..0.091 rows=0 loops=1)
           ->  Function Scan on unnest t  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=7 loops=1)
           ->  Unique  (cost=522.67..522.68 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=0 loops=7)
                 ->  Sort  (cost=522.67..522.67 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=7)
                       Sort Key: my_people.id
                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                       ->  Index Scan using department on people my_people  (cost=0.56..522.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=7)
                             Index Cond: (((department_type)::text = 'Some_department'::text) AND (department_id = t.fid))
                             Filter: ((company_type)::text = 'Some_company'::text)
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 0
 Planning Time: 0.248 ms
 Execution Time: 0.120 ms
(14 rows)
```

When using "company", the index scan has the lowest cost, so I think this is the reason why psql would use this index. However, this behavior would drastically slow my query down, I would like to know how psql determine which index to use.

Update 1:

I tried `VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) people;` and here's the output. It seems like nothing has changed but now my query uses the index I need.

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) people;
INFO:  vacuuming "people"
INFO:  index "people_pkey" now contains 66865768 row versions in 183343 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.11 s, system: 0.41 s, elapsed: 3.24 s.
INFO:  index "unique_person" now contains 66865768 row versions in 867318 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.54 s, system: 1.97 s, elapsed: 6.13 s.
INFO:  index "department" now contains 66865768 row versions in 308674 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.21 s, system: 0.67 s, elapsed: 1.32 s.
INFO:  "people": found 0 removable, 66865768 nonremovable row versions in 1943422 out of 1943422 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 85284
There were 0 unused item identifiers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 6.00 s, system: 13.11 s, elapsed: 30.15 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_1418456"
INFO:  index "pg_toast_1418456_index" now contains 2344 row versions in 9 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  "pg_toast_1418456": found 0 removable, 2344 nonremovable row versions in 534 out of 534 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 85284
There were 0 unused item identifiers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  analyzing "people"
INFO:  "people": scanned 30000 of 1943422 pages, containing 1032582 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 66891419 estimated total rows
VACUUM
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: 6 million rows is not considered "huge" these days

Comment: Besides needing the EXPLAIN, let me point out two issues. There is never a need in PostgreSQL to have an index on both X, Y, Z, W and X, Y. It is smart enough to use the former ignoring the last two columns. So the "company" index is redundant. Second, remember to ANALYZE the table after filing it.

Comment: The company index seems quite efficient to find zero rows that match the condition. The query runs in 2 milliseconds - how fast do you need that to be?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have this view that will execute this query thousand times, it would be pretty slow by then

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The query plan has been updated, you'll see it is way slower if I let postgresql choose index.

Comment: "will execute this query thousand times" What changes from execution to execution?  Rather than running the query 1000 times, maybe you could get all 1000 answers from one query using a join or group by?

Comment: "you'll see it is way slower if I let postgresql choose index"  We don't know how much of that is just due to caching effects.  Add BUFFERS to your explain analyze, and turn on track_io_timing.

Answer (score 0):

The best index here, which you don't currently have, might be one which covers the entire query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON people (company_type, department_type, department_id, company_id);
```

The two indices you have on the company and department columns each only partially cover the where clause.  Maybe that's enough, and Postgres would be happy enough to do a scan of that index and lookup the missing information.  The suggestion I gave above covers the where and select clauses, meaning that Postgres would not even have to reference the `people` table to satisfy your query.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is very generic, so I am assuming you are looking for ways to figure such things out in general, not for a canned answer to your specific scenario.

The EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the planner-preferred plan has:

```
Rows Removed by Filter: 1189
```

But, the EXPLAIN output doesn't tell you how many rows it *expected* to remove with the filter, only how many it actually did. (This lack of info is arguably a defect in EXPLAIN ANALYZE). Based on the low total cost estimate, it seems like it did not expect to remove that many. You can run a variant query to see how many rows it expected the index to return (all but 1 of which it silently expected the filter to remove):

```
explain select * from person where company_type = 'Some_company'
```

For the index you actually want it to use, the plan is also a bit baffling:

```
             ->  Index Scan using department on people my_people  (cost=0.56..503435.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.066..0.067 rows=0 loops=1)
                   Index Cond: (((department_type)::text = 'Some_department'::text) AND (department_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}'::integer[])))
                   Filter: ((Company_type)::text = 'Some_company'::text)
                   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
```

Instead of the cost here seeming too small for the large number of "Removed by Filter", now it seems very much too high for the low number of filtered rows.  But again we can only see how many rows it actually removed, not how many it expected to.  To see how many it expected this index scan to find before filtering, you can run:

```
explain select * from person where department_type = 'Some_department' AND department_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}'::integer[])
```

Comment: ```
explain select * from people where company_type = 'Some_company';
                                      QUERY PLAN                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using unique_person on people  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=174)
   Index Cond: ((company_type)::text = 'Some_company'::text)
(2 rows)
```
I tried run the explain but I still don't know what is the expected Row Removed by Filter.
I don't quite understand how indexes work in postgres and why a multi-column index will filter instead

Comment: The thing that I do now is to read the postgres opensource code and just try to figure out how it actually pick a index from another.

Comment: So it think only 1 row will meet `company_type = 'Some_company'`, but actually many more do.  So your stats are way off.  Did you run a VACUUM ANALYZE on the table recently?

Comment: No I didn't run VACUUM ANALYZE. And 1189 rows will meet `company_type = 'Some_company'`.

Comment: So vacuum analyze will probably fix the problem.  If it does, then the question is 'why doesn't autovac do well enough on its own?'

Comment: So I tried VACCUM ANALYZE and it works! I updated the question and add the VACCUM log. I'm still wondering why VACCUM will help, I'll dig into what it does. Thanks a lot!